# Find objects that lie within specific distance using IF statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, distance

in my script I am returning all items that fall within a 50KM radius of the users current location like so

```
 //user's current location
  $events = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $aryEvents = [];
        foreach ($events as $event) {
            $distance = distanceGeoPoints($event['event_latitude'], $event['event_longitude'], $params['user_latitude'], $params['user_longitude']);
        //for events greater than or equal to distance than that of coordinates
            if($distance >= 50) {
                continue;
            }
```

the DistanceGeopoints() function

```
 function distanceGeoPoints ($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {

$earthRadius = 6371;

$dLat = deg2rad($lat2-$lat1);
$dLon = deg2rad($lon2-$lon1);


$a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) +
   cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) *
   sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2);
$c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a));
$dist = $earthRadius * $c;

return $dist;
}
```

I am trying to understand 2 things
1. Why does the greater than ">=" return objects that are within this radius (this is what I want I just do not understand why)

2. When I attempt to find a specific event within a 30m radius it places the events in order of distance, which is not what I want. I only want a specific event(s) within this smaller radius, otherwise they should be in their original order,
   this is my attempt to solve this below

   ```
    if ($distance >= 0.03 && $event['event_user_id'] != 0) {
               $inserted = array($event);

               array_splice($aryEvents,0,0,$inserted);
           } else {
              array_push($aryEvents, $event);
           }
   ```

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: because `contune` means skip the rest of the loop, so its throwing out results where distance is greater than 50

Comment: I see, so to resolve this issue I should execute a continue command following the 30m conditional @rtfm